How to get global rotation of object without limits using Godot
I need to get a global rotation of an object without the limitation of -180 and 180 degrees. I need the global rotation to be able to be obtained from minus infinite to infinite

Check out the global_rotation property. Seems like it might be what you're looking for. https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/search.html?q=global_rotation&check_keywords=yes&area=default

Rotation will always be between -180 to 180 because it wraps around.  If it was -181, it would be 179
